# Will this character appear in the Justice League movie?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, justice-league

In the new Zack Snyder movie "Batman v Superman"

> Superman sacrifices himself in order to kill Doomsday

The end of the movie leaves us wondering if he will return, with a bit of a "inception"-like last scene. The question is:

> Will Superman be part of the Justice League in the upcoming movie, or is/was his casting just a ruse to suprise people with his demise in "Batman v Superman"?

Or shorter:

> Is Superman really dead?

Is there any storyline in the comics, where

> he returns from the dead?

(I tried to keep this question as spoiler-hidden as possible)

Comment: **_SPOILER!!_** I think Superman is alive. That's why some of the mud particles defied gravity and started floating upwards in the last scene of the movie. Obviously Superman doesn't need oxygen to survive (since he can survive in outer space). So what human method of identifying if he's still alive would work on him? I believe he was in a sort of "meta-human coma" and was just coming to at the last scene of the movie.

Comment: Voting to close based on our [future works policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5187/5184).

Comment: I don't believe this question should be closed, as there seems to already be a WoG answer - Snyder stated that he wants Batman to lead the Justice League in the film, and that would be impossible with Superman around: http://collider.com/batman-v-superman-ending-justice-league/

Comment: Unfortunately, there are three questions here - "Will Superman be part of the Justice League in the upcoming movie?" (No, according to Snyder), "Is Superman really dead?" (Future works question), and "Did Superman come back from the dead in the comics?" (Yes).

Comment: Given the very blatant Christ allegory this version of Superman is, it's pretty much certain he'll come back eventually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the end of the movie there is a definite hint that

> Soil begins to levitate off Superman's coffin - definite implication that he is coming back

Plus there is a rather large comic series called

> The death and return of Superman, where he is killed by... Doomsday! So I think the allusions in the film to the comic book are pretty strong. Now whether or not Superman will return at the start middle or end of the Justice League movie that is up for debate [image: Death and Return of Superman Comics]

Comment: There's also the clearly-audible heart beats coming from the coffin.

Comment: @TylerH Yes, and I think it would have been much better not to show the soil levitating on top off the coffin, because these beats are subtle-yet-sufficient enough ! Plus it's a strong node to TDKR's ending.

Answer (score 1):

In comic books it's actually pretty common to ["kill" off a character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comic_book_death) (see [Jean Grey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Grey), who is probably the most killed and revived superhero anywhere without innately possessing that as a power) and then tease that character's return. Considering that Superman is considered the cornerstone of the Justice League, would be pretty hard to have a movie that leaves out one of the central characters.

> In the 90s there was a fairly major earthquake in the DC comic world [when they killed Superman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Death_of_Superman). He was killed by a character named Doomsday (note that Doomsday then was not the same as Doomsday in the movie). DC then teased the whole world without a Superman premise and had not one, but 4 "Superman"s (one of whom was closer to Iron Man than Superman) appear. Of course the original eventually returned.

Comment: Speaking of Iron Man, our trio so far consists of a flying, godlike being from another world, a billionaire industrialist CEO with no superpowers but enough resources to build himself a powered armor suit for fighting bad guys, and a shield-bearing soldier who fought in one of the World Wars.  This sounds familiar!  Now they just need to bring in Green Arrow, Black Canary and... and... uhh... crap.  DC doesn't really have a good Hulk equivalent, now do they?

Comment: @MasonWheeler Lobo... kinda... (closer to Wolverine really) I mean he has held his own against Superman. But Hulk is Hulk like Batman is Batman.

Comment: I present to you: Rampage! Powers gained from radiation accident: check! Turns into a large, muscular, colorful monster when angry:  Check! Initially uncontrollable and destructive: Check! Learns to control said transformation: Check. Solomon Grundy *looks* more like the Hulk, but that is largely superficial. http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Karen_Lou_Faulkner_(New_Earth)